# Codekit and Jekyll Issue

Tags: jekyll, codekit

I am having an issue when compiling with Codekit in a Jekyll project.

codekit is having issues with the dashes on the top of the SCSS project.

```
---
# Only the main Sass file needs front matter (the dashes are enough)
---

@import
        "setup",
        "base",
        "layout"
;
```

The error from code kit is

Libsass: Error: Invalid CSS after "-": expected 1 selector or at-rule, was "---"
        on line 1:1 of Users/XXXX/XXXX/XXX/css/main.scss

> > ---

Im pretty new to Jekyll and code kit so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Jekyll has its own inbuilt [sass processor](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) which requires the dashes (otherwise known as front matter) as a marker to target this file for processing. CodeKit has an issue with these dashes as they are not valid sass code, only Jekyll can recognise them.

You can remove these dashes from your main sass file, as CodeKit will be processing your sass. Without these dashes, Jekyll will treat it as a standard file and copy it over to your compiled site.